# UILabel Color not set immediately when data loaded inside tableview

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uilabel

Based on response data trying to set UILabel background and text color.
From my below code its only setting when I am scrolling tableview.
When immediately loaded response data Need to set UILabel background & Text Color

```
    func setBackGroundTextColors(jobType: String) -> (UIColor,UIColor) {
       guard  stringValue ==  "YES" else {
            return ( #colorLiteral(red: 0.6784313725, green: 0.9529411765, blue: 0.9882352941, alpha: 1) , #colorLiteral(red: 0.5058823529, green: 0.4549019608, blue: 0.8980392157, alpha: 1) )
        }
        return ( #colorLiteral(red: 1, green: 0.9490196078, blue: 0.8941176471, alpha: 1) , #colorLiteral(red: 1, green: 0.4901960784, blue: 0, alpha: 1) )
}
```

CellforRowAtIndexPath

```
        let trueValue = data[indexPath.row].trueValue
         cell.lbl_Name?.backgroundColor =  self.setBackGroundTextColors(jobType: trueValue).0
        cell.lbl_Name?.textColor =  self.setBackGroundTextColors(jobType: trueValue).1
```

Comment: I assume you mis-typed: `guard  stringValue ==  "YES"` and you meant `guard  jobType ==  "YES"`? Second, are you sure your data array is filled correctly when the view loads? Or are you running an async function to "get the data"?

Comment: Can you post your entire cellForRow method?

Comment: Here’s my guess for what’s happening. When you receive a new color, you are updating your model (whatever that may be), but you are not reloading the cell. When the cell goes off screen and cellForIndexPath is called, it’s automatically reloaded and the color is updated.

Comment: post where you are reloading tableview ....